# Reading textarea values per row: what is the internal method?

Tags: forms

If I'd like to create a textarea field for a admin configuration form that would include different configurations on multiple rows then how can I read these values/rows?

I know there must be a internal method for this since it is very common form field/input type. I just wouldn't like to invent it again.

And I just ran into a module that was using this same principal but it matched the rows with regex \n\r which turned into few gray hairs if you had only one value since it didn't then match if you didn't deliberately press enter. And for clarity it obviously didn't check that if the first line included text, just that regex and therefore no settings were saved.

That was also a wake up for that there must be some more intelligent and elegant way...

Answer (score -1):

Drupal doesn't provide a method for that.

Just use whatever PHP splitting method makes sense for your use case. A very simple example might be:

```
$text = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r"), "\n", $text);
$vals = explode("\n", $text);
```

Comment: Sorry for downvote, but I believe your first sentence is simply invalid. See my answer.

Comment: No apology necessary @Mołot...I believe you're wrong though, I'll comment on your answer

Comment: I tried to figure out how it is done in Block module (visibility per path), but I couldn't find how the $block->pages property is actually set and used. Only thing I could find was a trim($form['values']['pages']) which removes all \n \r and "empty space" characters. Seems like every path is now a joined string which is later used to eval a match with current page's path. Makes sense since now it can use only one line of code to evaluate instead of looping over a number of paths.